# List view needs a specific sort

Tags: list, view

I have a list that I need to view in a certain way. I have date required and priority level columns. I need the view to be set so that when two users put a request in for the same date required, it will have the higher priority one first. If they have the same date required and priority level, then its fine.

How do I make this happen? I tried sort but it only sorted by date. I created two request required for the same date and the higher priority one was below the lower priority one.

Answer (score 0):

In List View you can sort by multiple fields.

You should [Sort](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-server-help/list-view-web-part-HA010024052.aspx) by `Date` and then `Priority Number`

Comment: Yeah I tried that. It still is not prioritizing them. I ran a test and put two request to be required on the same date. It ranked the lower priority one first. How can I make it rank the higher priority one first, then the lower one next?